# Implementing pipes in Java

Tags: java

Need advise on how to implement pipes in Java. Eg,

```
echo "test"|wc
```

I need to show results of the above pipe example.

I have tried this:

```
public class myRunner {

  private static final String[] cmd = new String[] {"wc"};
  public static void main(String[] args){       
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( cmd );
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);           
        Process process = pb.start();
        OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
        os.write("echo test".getBytes() );
        os.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can I view the output of `wc` output?

I believe another one of the library i can use is `PipedInputStream`/`PipedOutputStream`. Can anyone show an example on how to use it? Am quite confused. thanks

Comment: Can you post what you've tried, what you expect it to do and what it does?

Comment: see http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=464749

Comment: Check this post to get clarity of PipedInputSteam[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395714/use-cases-of-pipedinputstream-and-pipedoutputstream?lq=1]

Comment: `PipedInput/OutputStreams` are irrelevant to this problem. They are for communicating between threads, not between processes, and when between threads you are almost invariably better off using a Queue of some kind, as stated in my answer to @SureshKoya's cited thread.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I view the output of wc output?

By consuming the `Process's` output, via `Process.getInputStream()`, and reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<String> executorPiped(String[] cmd, String outputOld){
    String s=null;
    ArrayList<String> out=new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( cmd );
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();
        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
        os.write(outputOld.getBytes());
        os.close();

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            out.add(s);
        }
    }catch (IOException io){

    }
    return out;
}
```